# Can I deploy an angular site to any web hosting provider?

Tags: angular, hosting, web-hosting, namecheap

Can I host my angular 5 site to any web hosting provider?

If I do "ng build --prod" can I just deploy everything in the dist folder to the hosting provider? or does angular require you to find a specific web hosting service?

I was trying to use either Namecheap hosting or 000webhosting but I wanted to make sure it works.

Comment: You can host angular application any server you want

Comment: Basically every server that has the ability to host a static website is enough to serve the purpose.

Answer (score 4):

You can also host the build files on an Apache server. I just copied them to the htdocs directory and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes!. Consider the **dist/** folder created to be a static folder containing index.html.

You can use any web hosting services to serve **index.html** in the dist folder.

I am using nodejs to serve the **dist/** folder. If you want do the following procedure.

Create **app.js** file in root level and copy the following code;

```
const express = require('express'),
http    = require('http'),
path    = require('path');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));

app.get('*', (req,res) => {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'dist/index.html'));
})

const port = process.env.PORT || '4201';
app.set('port', port);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port,() => console.log('Running at port '+port))
```

Then install express

```
npm install --save express
```

Make sure you have made the build

now do `node app.js`

if you have want the same in AWS Web services

send your dist to aws server ec2 instance

Install [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)

Now `pm2 start app.js`.

Congrats you have hosted your application in aws.

Comment: Since Angular is just static html, css and js files couldn't you just host it on a CDN like S3/Cloudfront or Azure's blog storage/CDN?